# belongs_to more than one associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, models, belongs-to

Sorry for this nooby question.

Reading this here : [guides.rugyonrails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association)

It says that the belongs_to association is appropriate when each book can be assigned to exactly one author. But what is the best practice if a book can have several authors?

I need a table Books and a table Authors, where Books can have 1 to 10 authors.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

`has_many` is the answer for you. So in the Book model `has_many :authors` and the Author model `belongs_to :book`. You should read [has_many association rubyonrails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-association)